# Runninng next instance of job only after current instance completes?

Tags: spring-batch

Let's say I am writing a Spring Batch job and configuring it to run every 10 seconds. What would happen if an iteration of the job takes longer than 10 seconds to complete? Will Spring Batch kick off the next iteration at the scheduled time, or would it wait for the current iteration to complete? In the former case, is there a way to prevent the next job instance from starting until the current job iteration is complete?

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on what mechanism is being used to execute the job on a 10 second interval. But if you have the `restartable` flag set to false in the job definition than it will not kick off the next iteration until the current instant is complete. You would have to set up the scheduler to handle the scenario where it can't start the job and to handle it as you want.

```
<job id="myTask" restartable="false">
    ...
</job>
```

See [SpringBatch documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html#restartability).